# How to send array of items to localstorage within context api? (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, local-storage, react-context

I'm developing a pokedex using pokeAPI through react, but I'm developing a feature where I can favorite pokemons and with that through a context, I can store the names of these pokemons in a global array. I've already managed to test and verify that the pokemon names are going to this "database" array inside the pokeDatabase const in my context, but my goal now is to pass this array to localstorage so that the browser recognizes these favorite pokemons instead of disappearing every time I refresh the page, my solution was to try to create a useEffect inside the context so that every time I refresh my application, this information is saved in localStorage, but without success. What better way to achieve this?

context:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const CatchContext = createContext({
    pokemons: null,
});

export default CatchContext;
```

provider

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import CatchContext from "./Context";

const pokeDatabase = {
    database: [],
};

const CatchProvider = ({ children }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const dataStorage = async () => {
            await localStorage.setItem('pokemons', JSON.stringify(pokeDatabase.database)); 
        } 
        dataStorage();
    }, [])

    return (
        <CatchContext.Provider value={{ pokemons: pokeDatabase }}>
            {children}
        </CatchContext.Provider>
    );
}
 
export default CatchProvider;
```

pageAddPokemon

```
import * as C from './styles';

import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useApi } from '../../hooks/useApi';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import PokeInfo from '../../components/PokeInfo';

import AddCircleOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCircleOutline';
import DoNotDisturbOnIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DoNotDisturbOn';
import CatchContext from '../../context/Context';

const SinglePokemon = () => {
    const api = useApi();
    const { pokemons } = useContext(CatchContext);
    const { name } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleHompage = () => {
      navigate('/');
    }
  
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [imgDatabase, setImgDatabase] = useState('');
    const [infoPokemon, setInfoPokemon] = useState([]);
    const [pokemonTypes, setPokemonTypes] = useState([]);

    const [isCatch, setIsCatch] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const singlePokemon = async () => {
            const pokemon = await api.getPokemon(name); 
            setLoading(true);
            setImgDatabase(pokemon.sprites);
            setInfoPokemon(pokemon);
            setPokemonTypes(pokemon.types); 
            setLoading(false); 
            console.log(pokemons.database);
        }
        singlePokemon(); 
        verifyPokemonInDatabase();
    }, []);

    const verifyPokemonInDatabase = () => {
      if (pokemons.database[infoPokemon.name]) {
        return setIsCatch(true);
      } else {
        return setIsCatch(false); 
      }
    }

    const handleCatchAdd = async () => { 
      if (isCatch === false) { 
        if (!pokemons.database[infoPokemon.name]);
        pokemons.database.push(infoPokemon.name);
        setIsCatch(true);
      }
    }

    const handleCatchRemove = async () => { 
      if (isCatch === true) {
        if (!pokemons.database[infoPokemon.name]);
        pokemons.database.splice(pokemons.database.indexOf(toString(infoPokemon.name)), 1);
        setIsCatch(false);
      }
    }


  return (
    <C.Container>
      <PokeInfo 
        name={infoPokemon.name}
      /> 
      <C.Card>
        <C.Info>
          <C.Imgs>
            <img src={imgDatabase.front_default} alt="" />
            <img src={imgDatabase.back_default} alt="" />
          </C.Imgs>
          <h2 id='types'>Tipos</h2>
          {pokemonTypes.map(type => {
            return (
              <C.Types>
                <h2>{type.type.name}</h2>
              </C.Types>
            )
          })}
          {isCatch ?  (
            <DoNotDisturbOnIcon id='iconCatched' onClick={handleCatchRemove}/>
          ): <AddCircleOutlineIcon  id='icon' onClick={handleCatchAdd}/>}
        </C.Info>
      </C.Card>
      <C.Return>
        <button onClick={handleHompage}>Retornar a Pokédex</button>
      </C.Return>
    </C.Container>
  )
}

export default SinglePokemon;
```

Comment: when you try to store it in the localStorage, what do you see if you go to localStorage on devTools?

Comment: In localStorage, the array is empty only

Comment: It stays there, but the items are not added